# How do I use pyodbc with jupyterhub?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, jupyterhub, pymssql

I need to connect to a mssql server through Jupyterhub. Using pyodbc with sqlalchemy fails since it cannot find the odbc driver installed on my local machine and with pymssql I get Adaptive Server connection failed error.

I am assuming the server does not allow connection with pymssql since I could not connect it using Jupyter notebook on my local machine as well but was able to connect it through pyodbc.

Is there a way to install sql server odbc driver on Jupyterhub environment?

Comment: If you have sudo access via a Jupyter Terminal can't you just install ODBC Driver 17/18 for SQL Server (following [instructions appropriate to your operating system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)) or FreeTDS? If you don't have that level of access have you considered using a pure Python TDS driver, so that you don't need external dependencies, such as python-tds.